# Rails Getting Error uninitialized constant ApplicationController (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error of ApplicationBaseController where it is throwing up a name error. Is there anything wrong in both of these codes because ruby is throwing errors even though i'm inheriting from the applicationbasecontroller in the application controller

```
class ShoppingController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all()
  end

  def new

  end

  def showcollection
    @products =Product.where(category_id: params[:id])
    @productcount = Product.where(category_id: params[:id]).count
  end




  def create_product
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    if (@product.save())
      redirect_to shopping_index_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  
  private def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name,:price, :category_id, :image)
  end

  end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

Also here is my directory structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdbbo.jpg)

Comment: should it be ActionController::API?

Comment: Can you post the full error message including the stack trace and tell what you did when the error was raised (starting server, using the console, requesting a URL)?